# Show window with exception when any occur

Tags: java, exception

I need to somehow summon window with exception message and report button when any occur. I don't even know how to chceck trough code is there any exception. I want something like in minecraft - when game crashes there is launcher window saying that exception occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Once an exception is caught, it is caught. Note that exceptions are caught all the time as part of normal control flow, so you don't want this, even if you think you do.

What you may want is to register an uncaught exception handler: That doesn't catch *all* exceptions. Only the ones that bubble up to the top of a given thread.

Unfortunately, a ton of java examples tend to write:

```
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

which is stupid code. And this question shows why: It is now 'caught' and there's not much you can do.

Assuming you wrote your code properly, and all exceptions are allowed to bubble up (i.e. you wrote `throw new RuntimeException("Uncaught", e);`, or better yet added a `throws` clause on your methods listing the checked exceptions you are not handling), then:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler((thread, ex) -> {
    // do whatever you want here.
    // if you are going to do GUI stuff, remember to
    // wrap it in SwingUtilities.invokeLater or
    // a worker or whatnot - you are not in the EDT here.
    // 'ex' holds the exception.
});
```

Comment: THAKS! IT WORKED! :D

Comment: Can I somehow check what exception it was or get Exception info?

Comment: `ex` is the exception, so, yes: `ex.getClass()` will give you e.g. `java.lang.NumberFormatException`, `ex.getMessage()` gets you the message, `ex.getStackTrace()` the trace, `ex.getCause()` the cause, etc. Just check the API docs of `java.lang.Throwable`.

Answer (score 0):

put all of your code inside a trycatch block like this

```
    try
{
 //your code
}catch(Exception e)
{
   int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, //parent component
                e.getMessage(), //your error message
                "Do you want to report?", //title of window
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, // option yes
                JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, //optionno
                null);//icon
        if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) //if option is yes then report
        {
            //how to handle report code
        } 
        else 
        {
            //user do not want to report do something
        }
}
```

Comment: i don't want try catch exceptions, i want every, event without try catch, for example NullPointerException